# Filtrar banco de dados por checkbox

Tags: checkbox, filtro

Esse exibe todos os dados...

```
public function getProdutosHome($limit = false){
    if($limit == false){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `fretes` ORDER BY id_frete DESC";   
    }else{
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `fretes` ORDER BY id_frete DESC LIMIT $limit";
    }
    return self::conn()->query($query);
}
```

Como posso filtrar usando *checkbox* ? a cada clique ir filtrando os dados do banco de dados ?

Obrigado e desculpem pela pergunta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vai ter que fazer por ajax. Setar em cada checkbox um onchange chamando a função ajax pegando as checkbox selecionadas.

Comment: Mor retorno do ajax, sete o elemento que será alterado.

Comment: ok obrigado pela dica e funcionou. Mas quando clico no checkbox para desabilitar ele não exibe todos os dados novamente. fica mostrando os valores que foram filtrado pela checkbox.

Comment: tenho que dar refresh na pagina para carregar todos os dados novamente.

Comment: Tá executando o ajax somente quando o checkbox tá checked? Tem que ser quando tiver mudança.

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#Rodotrem").on('change',function()
      {
   var value = $(this).val();
   $.ajax(
   {
    url:'fetch.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:'request='+value,
    beforeSend:function()
    {
     $("#content_produtos").html("Filtrando..."); 
    },
    success:function(data)
    {
     $("#content_produtos").html(data);
    },
    
   });
  });